# android hide title in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have started working in fragment. I am trying to hide  `titleBar` in fragment, but i have this Log-cat Error

```
android fragment requestfeature must be called before adding content
```

this is a source

```
public class SendItemsFragment extends Fragment {

Button b1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.send_items, container, false);



    return rootView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Put this in your Activity   `getActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` because `Fragment` is just `Block`. It's attach to your `Activity`. so need to Hide title of your `Activity`

Comment: then he does not need getactivity

Comment: yes i know how to hide title in Activity,but i use Slide Menu and i need to  hide title in fragment.it is a possible to hide tittle in fragment?

Comment: You cannot request a window feature after the Window has already been created. You should ask the activity to hide its actionbar.

Answer (score 9):

**This is what worked for me:**

Hide action bar

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your code as

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

in `onCreate` function instead of,

`getActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

```
public class SendItemsFragment extends Fragment {
   private Activity activity;
   public SendItemsFragment (Activity act) {
       this.activity = act;
   }

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         activity.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.send_items, container, false);
         return rootView;
   }
}
```

Comment: i changed it but  i have same result :( nothink changed

Comment: You can send the context of your main activity to your fragment via constructor of the SendItemsFragment class.

Check the edit above it will help you

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call this method after setting contentView in Activity (LogCat answers your question already). You can do nothing about that. You must change your Fragment to Activity, or design your application in a different way. Eventually you can only hide title from Actionbar

```
getActivity().getActionBar().hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The other answers in this post of setting

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
in the Activity before loading the fragment didn't work. What worked was this:
In the AndroidManifest.xml application tag I had this:

android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight"

and the issue was resolved by including a NoActionBar suffix:

android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.**NoActionBar**"

Answer (score 0):

In Manifest file, change label declare in activity is empty is my solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's a better workaround:

```
(activity as MainActivity).supportActionBar?.title = ""
```

**Make sure to change it before setting the content:**

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        (activity as MainActivity).supportActionBar?.title = ""
        binding = LoginFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }
```